Bitvise SSH client: Terminal console does not work?
Wnen I connect to my work  computer with the  Bitvise SSH client, a   Terminal  console icon appears on its sidebar, and  this icon actually opens a terminal console with PowerShell, but this console is on the local computer. I expected it to be on the remote computer. What am I doing wrong? The server on the remote computer is also Bitvise SSH server. I didn't find whether there are any settings for the terminal console in the sercer's Control Panel. I guess, default settings are left.
